# How to create an inverse gray scale?

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I have an **image with dark blue spots on a black background**. **I want to convert this to *inverse* gray scale.** By inverse, I mean, I want the black ground to be white.

When I convert it to gray scale, it makes everything look black and it makes it very hard to differentiate.

1. Is there a way to do an inverse gray scale where the black background takes the lighter shades?
2. Or, another *preferable* option is to represent the blue as white and the black as black.

I am using `img = rgb2gray(img);` in MATLAB for now.

Comment: you can try to visualize using `imagesc(img)`. You can also try to `new_img = 1-img` and visualize that.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. :/

Comment: OR 255-img, depends on the data type

Comment: Do you have a sample image?

Comment: @beaker the accepted answer's sample picture is pretty spot on.

Comment: Then you should be able to achieve your second option by taking just the blue channel `img(:,:,3) > 0`.

Comment: Yep, I actually asked a follow up question and figured out the answer myself and posted that.

Comment: Cool, I only saw the comment on the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to do an inverse gray scale where the black
>      background takes the lighter shades?

Based on your image description I created an image `sample.png`:

```
img1 = imread('sample.png');        % Read rgb image from graphics file.
imshow(img1);                       % Display image.
```

[image: original image]

Then, I used the [`imcomplement`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcomplement.html) function to obtain the complement of the original image (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689636/3599179)).

```
img2 = imcomplement(img1);          % Complement image.
imshow(img2);                       % Display image.
```

This is the result:

[image: complement image]

> 2. Or, another preferable option is to represent the blue as white and
>      the black as black.

In this case, the simplest option is to work with the blue channel. Now, depending on your needs, there are two approaches you can use:

### Approach 1: Convert the blue channel to a binary image (B&W)

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689224/how-to-create-an-inverse-gray-scale/43689853#comment74450973_43689224) suggests using the [logical operation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) `img(:,:,3) > 0`, which will return a binary array of the blue channel, where every non-zero valued pixel will be mapped to `1` (white), and the rest of pixels will have a value of `0` (black).

While this approach is simple and valid, [binary images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image) have the big disadvantage of loosing [intensity information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity). This can alter the perceptual properties of your image. Have a look at the code:

```
img3 = img1(:, :, 3) > 0;           % Convert blue channel to binary image.
imshow(img3);                       % Display image.
```

This is the result:

[image: binary image]

Notice that the round shaped spots in the original image have become octagon shaped in the binary image, due to the loss of intensity information.

### Approach 2: Convert the blue channel to grayscale image

A better approach is to use a [grayscale image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale), because the intensity information is preserved.

The `imshow` function offers the `imshow(I,[low high])` overload, which adjusts the [color axis scaling](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) of the grayscale image through the [DisplayRange](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_DisplayRange) parameter.

One very cool feature of this overload, is that we can let `imshow` do the work for us.

From the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_DisplayRange):

> If you specify an empty matrix `([])`, `imshow` uses `[min(I(:)) max(I(:))]`. In other words, use the minimum value in `I` as black, and the maximum value as white.

Have a look at the code:

```
img4 = img1(:, :, 3);               % Extract blue channel.
imshow(img4, []);                   % Display image.
```

This is the result:

[image: grayscale image]

Notice that the round shape of the spots is preserved exactly as in the original image.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the 2nd option I had listed?

Comment: @Christian I have updated my answer. I hope you find it useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[From mathworks site](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcomplement.html):

```
IM2 = imcomplement(IM)
```